# Populating a list based on its element type when passed to a method

Tags: c#

Not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to be able to populate a `List<T>` based on what `T` is.  Presently, I have something like this (please forgive the generic names - it's for testing purposes):

```
public static class CollectionsClass
{

    List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>();
    List<Object2> list2 = new List<Object2>();
    List<Object3> list3 = new List<Object3>();
}

public static class ActionClass
{
    public static void PopulateCollections()
    {
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list1, 0, 10);
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list2, 20, 50);
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list3, 30, 100);
    }

    private static void Populate(dynamic list, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
        for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
        {
            if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<Object1>))
            {
                list.Add(new Object1());
            }
            else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<Object2>))
            {
                list.Add(new Object2());
            }
            else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<Object3>))
            {
                list.Add(new Object3());
            }
            else
            {
                // put out an error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While that code works, I'd like to shrink it by doing something like:

```
list.Add(new list.ObjectType());
```

I've been messing around with reflections and getting types all day, but I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: You could use reflection to construct an instance of the objects dynamically. You would have to retrieve the item type of the list, and then create a new instance based on that. You may have to change the Populate method using Generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dynamics, use generics:

```
static void Populate<T>(List<T> list, ...) where T: new()
{
    ... 
    for (int i=0; i<rndNum; i++)
        list.Add(new T());
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see the answer here from your earlier comment.  Well done, sir.  I tried something like this earlier, but I forgot `where T: new()`.  By the way, you're missing `()` at the end of new.  But, other than that, works like a charm!  Thank you so much.

Comment: I received an amazing amount of great answers, many of which I'm studying piece by piece right now, but yours came before many other similar ones, and it works flawlessly, so I think you deserve the credit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using `dynamic`, you should be able to add method to handle this:

```
private static void AddToList<T>(List<T> list) where T : new()
{
    list.Add(new T());
}
```

Given that, you can write:

```
private static void Populate(dynamic list, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
    for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
    {
         AddToList(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is a mostly statically typed language. Static typing has a lot of benefits - a lot of bugs that occur in dynamically typed languages are caught by the C# compiler.

Comment: Oops, pressed ENTER too soon. Anyway, C# does support dynamic typing as you've tried, but in this case you gain absolutely nothing from using dynamic types. The question you should ask yourself is - what do I gain from using dynamics here.

Comment: @zmbq I see your point.  I definitely prefer the safer version, I just couldn't get it to work before.  Thanks to the abundance of amazing examples, including the one in your answer, I got it working now. :)

Comment: @zmbq Yes, unless there was other work being done.  Wasn't sure what else is involved in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use generic method:

```
public static class CollectionsClass
{
    public static List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>();
    public static List<Object2> list2 = new List<Object2>();
    public static List<Object3> list3 = new List<Object3>();
}

public static class ActionClass
{
    public static void PopulateCollections()
    {
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list1, 0, 10);
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list2, 20, 50);
        Populate(CollectionsClass.list3, 30, 100);
    }

    private static void Populate<T>(List<T> list, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
        where T : new()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
        for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new T());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a combination of generics and reflection.

First of all [make it generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx):

```
void Populate<T>(List<T> mylist)
```

Now you know the type of your list: it's `T`.

All that is left is looping and creating instances of a particular type `T`. For this you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    mylist.Add((T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));
}
```

With this sample code:

```
void Main()
{
    Populate<Type1>(new List<Type1>());
    Populate<Type2>(new List<Type2>());
}


void Populate<T>(List<T> mylist){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        mylist.Add((T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));
    }

    foreach(var item in mylist){
        Console.WriteLine (item);
    }
}



class Type1 { }
class Type2 { }
class Type3 { }
```

You get this output:

[image]

This will rely on reflection to create an instance of your object any assumes there is a public non-parameter constructor available (otherwise an exception will be thrown from the `Activator`).

This is not quite desirable behaviour and I realized it as soon as I saw the other answers that use the `where T : new()` constraint in their generic function: use this method over mine.

I'll still leave it in here for completeness though (at the very least it demonstrates a possible trap).

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer.  you've provided a lot of insightful information and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **generic with a `new` constraint** to achieve this:

```
private static void PopulateList<T>(List<T> list, int minLimit, int maxLimit) 
    where T : new()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
    for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
    {
         list.Add(new T());
    }
}
```

The constraint is that the type T must provide a default constructor. If you want to add items to a List, you do not need the `dynamic` keyword as you can specify `List<T>` as parameter type directly.

If you cannot add a default constructor, you can also provide a **creator function**:

```
private static void PopulateList<T>(List<T> list, Func<int, T> creatorFunc, 
                                    int minLimit, int maxLimit) 
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
    for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
    {
         list.Add(creatorFunc(i));
    }
}
```

You call the method like this:

```
var lst = new List<MyObjectType>();
PopulateList<MyObjectType>(lst, x => new MyObjectType(x), 1, 7);
```

In this sample, the value of `i` is provided to the creatorFunc that returns a new object of type `MyObjectType`.

Answer (score 1):

Use factory to extract the creation logic, reflection to get the correct type, and Activator to get the instance.

```
public static class TFactory 
{ 
    public static T Getmplementation<T>()
    {            
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException(typeName);
    }
}
```

Then,

List.Add(TFactory.GetImplmentation<'T>());